# Cannot link files within google colab. What am I doing wrong here. I've already mounted both drives

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am new to learning python and am trying to learn how to refer to another library within my own google drive. I feel like all the steps I've taken so far, but I keep getting that the module doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong here?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkQ9I.png)
[Proof of existance of Path and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4QUh.png)

I am very new to coding so any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Python modules can be created using Python scripts (`.py`). Therefore functions and classes cannot be imported from Python notebooks (`.ipynb`). So export the notebook file as a script file (many ways to do that: use VSCode, or Google Colab itself). Another change you need to make is, you need to provide the path of the directory which contains the script file to `sys.path` rather than the path of the file itself.

```
some_directory
- Sayings.py
- ....
- ....
- __init__.py (optional)
```

```py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '...../some_directory/')
from Sayings import hello
```